# JDownloader 2 getting sun.java2d.d3d=false error on startup in Debian Linux

Tags: debian, jdownloader

JDownloader 2 working good on other linux like ubuntu, mint etc but it is not starting on Debian linux and getting following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.java2d.d3d=false
```

Please anyone help me ???

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

Go to JDownloader directory (usually `~/jd2`) and open the file `JDownloader2.vmoptions` in a editor. The content of the file should be:

```
-Xms64m
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
```

(Notice the missing prefix `-D` in the original file).

Comment: Thank you, I was facing the same problem. This worked perfectly!